# Implement a 64 blocks logical disk using char array in c

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am really new to C....
The logical disk I want (lets call logdisk) has to have 64 blocks, each blocks is 64 bytes.

For example, 
logdisk[i][j], i is the number or index of logical blocks on logdisk, and j is the block length in bytes.

so,

logdisk[5][0] should give me the first byte of block 5.

But I am having trouble of creating this logdisk as I don't know how to allocate a 2d char array using malloc, I have the code below.

```
char *logdisk = malloc(64 * 64);
```

Can someone give tell me how to create a 2d char array with 64 64bytes blocks?

Thanks for commenting, now I get some clues,

```
char (*logdisk)[64] = malloc(64*64);
```

The one above is from Jasen, and the below one is my idea, which one should I use for 64*64 logical disk?

```
 char **logdisk = malloc(sizeof(char)*64); 
 for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
     logdisk[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*64); 
 }
```

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to achieve here. You're talking about logical disks -- fine, then do `char *logdisk=start_of_disk;`. Why are you trying to allocate an array of pointers to more arrays to describe something linear by definition?

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned char (*logdisk)[64] = malloc(64*64);
```

I used unsigned char, because char could be signed or unsigned depending on which compiler you use and most people consider bytes to be unsigned.

this defines logdisk as a pointer to a block (which is an array of 64 unsigned char),

then you can say logdisk[5][7] and have the seventh byte of block 5 etc...

Comment: unsigned char **logdisk[64] = malloc(sizeof(char)*64);

Comment: what about the sizeof(char*)? do I need it or not?

Comment: @Noah that first looks like a syntax error to me you `declare logdisk as array 64 of pointer to pointer to unsigned char`
but then try to initialise the array with a scalar. `sizeof(char)` is never needed it is always 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a `char **` to hold a two-dimensional array:

```
char **logdisk = malloc(64 * sizeof(char *)); // allocate block pointers
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 64; ++i) { // allocate each block
    logdisk[i] = malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Deallocation goes in the same way, but in reverse.

Comment: Yep :) This is what i just thought! but I only need 64*64 bytes, will the sizeof(char) * 64 * 64 give me a different memory?

Comment: and could you please tell me more about the deallocation? What do you mean by goes in the same way but in reverse?

Comment: @Noah `64*sizeof(char*)` is for allocating the array of 64 pointers note the `*` after `char` then the loop allocates each sector individually this time `64*sizeof(char)`  which comes out as `64`

Comment: @Noah Actually, this will allocate 64 * 64 chars but also 64 char pointers.

Comment: I don't think this is right, I think we should allocate a whole array in one time, if we do it in for loop, the memory is not contiguous.

Comment: @Noah Okay, but in my own defence you didn't mention that as a requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for 
either

```
malloc(sizeof(char) * 64 * 64)
```

Where byte x of disk y is accessed by

```
logdisk[y*64+x];
```

or

```
char **logdisk = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 64); 
for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    logdisk[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
```

with access of byte X of disk Y through

```
logdisk[Y][X];
```

Comment: Yep :) This is what i just thought! but I only need 64*64 bytes, will the sizeof(char) * 64 * 64 give me a different memory?

Comment: No, but it is good practice to use `sizeof` in  allocation in order to ensure proper memory size cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
I would do it this way:

#define MAX_DISK_BLOCK_LEN (64)
#define MAX_DISK_BLOCKS    (64)

struct diskBlock
{
    char diskBlock[MAX_DISK_BLOCK_LEN];
};


struct diskBlock * logDisk = malloc(MAX_DISK_BLOCKS*sizeof(struct diskBlock) );

if( NULL == logDisk )
{
    perror( "malloc for logDisk failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE _;
}

// implied else, malloc successful

logDisk[x].diskBlock[y]  to access the areas in this logDisk
                         remembering to keep 'x' to the range 0...(MAX_DISK_BLOCKS-1)
                         remembering to keep 'y' to the range 0...(MAX_DISK_BLOCK_LEN -1)
```